# How to search for multiple values in a string column in a Cognos Oracle Query

Tags: oracle, cognos, regexp-like

I need to search an oracle table column for multiple word strings in cognos oracle query.

For example:

If Focus parameter returns multiple values as below

`TRAINING`
`OMNIA`
`COUNTER`
`PROGRAM`

And I need to search project.proj_name column like '%TRAINING%' or '%OMNIA%' or '%COUNTER%' or '%PROGRAM%'

I am trying below but I know it does only single value match not multiple. I want to know how to achieve multiple value match here.

`'-99' in (#promptmany('Focus', 'string','-99')#) OR REGEXP_LIKE(proj_name, #promptmany('Focus', 'string','-99')#))`

Comment: In Oracle you could just use `column_name like '%TRAINING%' or column_name like '%OMNIA%' or column_name like '%COUNTER%' or column_name like '%PROGRAM%'`

Comment: No, it is a cognos report query, so values comes dynamically so I can't use as you described above. Oracle is the backend Database. Report user can select single value, or 2 values or more. I should do a wild card search on multiple values on that column data.

Comment: Any body can shed some light on this requirement?

Comment: If you want more visibility of the question then you can put a bounty on it; otherwise you are just going to have to wait for someone who knows Cognos and knows how to solve your issue to answer.

Comment: When you say that users can select one or more values, is this in a prompt?   Your terminology and problem description is awfully vague and subsequently difficult to answer. Is this for a filter?  By search, where are searching?  No matter what the like operator seems to be part of the solution.

Comment: Yes it is a prompt and for a filter.

Comment: The suggestion by @MT0 would be the correct pattern for part of a filter expression but that shouldn't have been too difficult to determine as a value or values returned by #prompt# or #promptmany# or ?prompt? will fit into the filter.  This suggests that the problem is that what you actually are seeking has not been properly defined.  Terminology is a problem too; there's no such thing as a 'focus filter' in Cognos IIRC.

Comment: I have further researched and fine tuned my query in the question above and now the expression looks like below:

`REGEXP_LIKE (proj_name,   #join('|', array(csv(split(',', promptmany('Focus', 'string','-99')))))#,'m')`
I am sending `PROGRAM`   `COUNTER` as two values for the prompt 'Focus' and now i am getting below error..
Data source adapter error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: Are you sure your reason for starting the bounty is correct?  It seems more likely you want to "draw attention".  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362601/the-answer-from-a-reputable-source-bounty-reason-seems-overused

Answer (score 1):

Working from [Cognos Paul's solution to use output from promptmany as a table](https://cognospaul.com/2018/12/13/quickie-prompt-parameters-rows/):

Assuming your query is named Q1...

1. Add a query. (Q2)
2. Add a SQL object to that query.
3. Set the Data source property for the SQL object.
4. Change the SQL Syntax property to IBM Cognos.
5. Define the query as

```
SELECT
    parameterValue
FROM (VALUES
  (#join('),(',split(',',promptmany('Scenarios','string',sq('N/A'))))#)
    ) query(parameterValue)
```

(change the names for your own use case)

6. Add a query. (Q3)
7. Add a join to the new query.
8. Add Q1 and Q2 to the empty boxes for the join leading to Q3.
9. Set the join as

```
[Q1].[proj_name] like '%' || [Q2].[parameterValue] || '%'
```

10. Add the required data items to Q3.

Since two keywords (from your parameter -> Q2) could be found in a single value (in Q1), you'll likely end up with duplicate rows.  Cognos will probably handle this with its default aggregations, but keep a lookout.

Be careful with this.  The new query (Q2) will probably be joined on the Cognos server, not on the database server.  Be sure you have sufficient filters leading into this structure so Cognos is not trying to process your entire database.

This worked for me with SQL Server.  I don't have an Oracle database to test against, but using IBM Cognos as the SQL Syntax should handle that.

Comment: Does Oracle/SQLServer support multiple wildcard search expressions in LIKE clause? It won't. So i am using REGEXP_LIKE (Oracle) and my expression is like this but throwing an error `ORA-00996: the concatenate operator is ||, not |`. So something is messing up in this below expression, I need a fix for this, that is the main purpose of my question here.

my SQL expression in cognos is : REGEXP_LIKE (proj_name,  #sq(join('|',split(',',promptmany('Focus','string','-99'))))#

Comment: The above should translate to REGEXP_LIKE (proj_name, 'PROGRAM|COUNTER|TRAINING') where i have selected PROGRAM COUNTER TRAINING in my 'Focus' prompt.

Comment: Oracle LIKE absolutely supports wildcard search expressions.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87ed2/3   Did you try my solution?  What errors do you get?

Comment: I didn't try exactly how you described because It won't be applicable for as is. my expression should be something like this. `proj.proj_name like ('%PRGORAM%', '%COUNTER%', '%TRAINING%')` and there can be `n` number of wildsearch phrases in the like clause in my case. Means i need to achieve LIKE and IN Clause functionality at the same time. when i run this directly in Oracle -  `REGEXP_LIKE (proj_name, 'PROGRAM|COUNTER|TRAINING')` - it is giving desired result.

Comment: I need to frame this in Cognos Oracle query something similar to `REGEXP_LIKE (proj_name, #sq(join('|',split(',',promptmany('Focus','string','-99'))))#` but this is throwing error on DB `ORA-00996: the concatenate operator is ||, not |`.

Comment: My answer will take 5 minutes to implement.  If you didn't try it, how do you know it won't work?

Answer (score 1):

To use `REGEXP_LIKE` to solve this problem, you'll need to get the second argument correct.  I can't see any reason to see the error message `ORA-00996: the concatenate operator is ||, not |`, but I'm not working with your code in your system.

You don't specify which version of Cognos, or even which Cognos product, you are using.  I'll assume Cognos Analytics 11.1.7.

To determine what Cognos Analytics is doing with your macro, create a very simple query with one item from the database (preferably from a very small table) and another data item that contains the macro.  So the data item expression is:

```
#sq(join('|',split(',',promptmany('Focus','string','-99'))))#
```

When you run this, you may not be prompted.  You'll see the value is `-99`.  So to test this we'll need to remove the default so that the prompt becomes required.

```
#sq(join('|',split(',',promptmany('Focus','string'))))#
```

Be sure to enter more than one value when you test.

In my environment, the parameter returns a value that is my values surrounded by quotes (`'`) and delimited by semicolons (`;`).  So my tests produced the following:

| expression | value |
| --- | --- |
| `#sq(promptmany('Focus','string'))#` | `'PROGRAM';'COUNTER';'TRAINING'` |
| `#sq(join('|',split(',',promptmany('Focus','string'))))#` | `'PROGRAM';'COUNTER';'TRAINING'` |
| `#sq(join('|',split(';',promptmany('Focus','string'))))#` | `'PROGRAM'|'COUNTER'|'TRAINING'` |
| `replace(#sq(join('|',split(';',promptmany('Focus','string'))))#, '''', '')` | `PROGRAM|COUNTER|TRAINING` |

Your mileage may vary.

At this point, you know which macro to use in the `REGEXP_LIKE` function.

Comment: I do believe that instead of having two different answers, you should combine both in a single one, explaining both approaches

Comment: They are distinctly different solutions.